# How to generate a Jar file for a Spring boot application which is running infinitely (Infinite loop)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, executable-jar

I know how to build a jar of an application with all the dependencies but here is the situation for me, 
when we build a jar (using mvn package), it first runs the application to check if everything is fine (meaning: application needs to stop successfully/properly). But for my case, the application doesn't stop since it's running an infinite loop and is not creating any jar.

Any help, please? 
I'm sorry if this question is a duplicate. I did search for this here and couldn't find any relative answers.

Pom.xml

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-beta-5</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>path.to.mainclass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assemble-all</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: What kind of program never stops?

Comment: A listener, maybe. I'm watching a folder for any change infinitely.
Please correct me, if the approach is wrong.

Comment: "... and is not creating any jar", that took me some time to understand. That does not refer to the application, but to the Maven invocation, right?

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht Yes. My purpose is to generate the jar. Since the application doesn't end/stop, it's not *generating* the jar. 
Apologies, if you didn't get the question properly.

Comment: To make things simpler, you should post the part of your pom.xml which causes the application execution.

Comment: Added pom.xml file.

Comment: There is no code in the pom.xml excerpt which would cause the application to run during build.

Comment: Strange. Because it does run the application while building it.

Comment: Then you should first of all understand what part of your pom.xml is doing what. Perhaps there are other plugins configured? Profiles? Parent POM?

Comment: Anybody, to help me with why my application runs when I build it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been more than 8 months since the question was asked, I think the OP might have found some solution or moved-on by now. Writing this answer for others encountering the same issue as I was also facing it and found the following solution.

As mentioned in the question, when you run **mvn package/install**, it first runs the application to check if everything is fine, and then creates the package/jar.

So, once you are confident that the application is fine, stop it and re-run **mvn package/install**, but this time **skip the test**. This can be done in any of the following ways.

1. If you are using Spring Tool Suite:
   Right click on project -> Run As -> Maven Build... -> In the Main tab, **select checkbox 'Skip Tests'** -> Apply -> Run
2. If you are running from command line:
   mvn package **-Dmaven.test.skip=true**
3. Also, you can set it in pom.xml file:
   `<properties>
       <java.version>1.8</java.version>
       <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
   </properties>`
   And run mvn package
4. If you are using Surefire plugin:
   mvn package **-DskipTests**

For further reference, please find source links below:

1. https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-skip-maven-unit-test/
2. http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-tests.html
3. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/it-skip.html

Comment: Yes, it's been solved. I solved it in the same exact way, by skipping the Tests.

Comment: @AmritKrLama, thanks for the response. Can you please upvote the answer as you have confirmed the solution?

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the answer, anyway.

Comment: Thanks @LohithVishwakarma. +1 from me.

Comment: @Amrit, you should upvote this answer. He spent time for you. You should respect this as well.